# Automatic subdomain Rewriterule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

i need subdomain from this url : http://domain.com/ad-1
For example: http://ad-1.domain.com/

My rewriterule on first url:

```
RewriteRule ad-([0-9_-]+)$ ad.php?id_cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thank you for answers !

Comment: This is not something you'd accomplish with a RewriteRule.

Comment: Do you have any idea please?

Comment: You'll need a wildcard subdomain and some code to parse `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to read something